# Uncontrolled textbox, update defaultValue

Tags: reactjs

I have an uncontrolled textbox. I set the `defaultValue` on it. When I change the `defaultValue` shouldn't it update/re-render the textbox? It is not doing so, does anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html):

> **Note:**
>
> The `defaultValue` and `defaultChecked` props are only used during initial render. If you need to update the value in a subsequent render, you will need to use a [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Comment: Aw drats, I was really hoping I could :( I'll write my own way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. I used the technique from the **Animating One or Zero Items** section on the **Animations** page - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animating-one-or-zero-items

Basically what you do is, set the `key` to the `defaultValue`, and it recreates the text field everytime.

So it is not impossible, just have to be a little bit creative. However this causes the old field to be removed and a new one to be created, so it is a performance hit, so not a truly great solution. But got it done.